# Tag creation and change log creation for Release branches

Tags: github-actions, release-notes, conventional-changelog

I have a main branch, I created a release branch release/sandbox/1.0.0 from main. I created a tag sandbox_prod_v1.0.0, the changelog will have commits from main to sandbox_prod_v1.0.0, More commits are made in the main after the release was tag sandbox_prod_v1.0.0,

Now I created another release branch from main release/sandbox/2.0.0. A new tag sandbox_prod_v2.0.0 is created and now I want to create changelog with commits from sandbox_prod_v1.0.0 -sandbox_prod_v2.0.0 and main -sandbox_prod_v1.0.0.
How will I do it?

I am using github actions to create the tags. And using conventional-changelog to create the release notes.

I was thinking of merging the tags prefixed by sandbox_prod_v in the new release branch release/sandbox/2.0.0.
And expecting the new branch will have all the tags to generate the release notes as expected.

But need some confirmation if the approach looks ok.

Comment: Conceptually, this sounds OK, but if you're not sure, I would test it in a dummy repo and see what happens.